# Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.DataGrid - how to get cell value from button click on the cell

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid, windows-community-toolkit

Using [Microsoft.Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview), I'm populating [UWP Tookit DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid) as follows.

**Question**: How can I get the value of the selected cell on a click event of a button on the cell?

**Code to populate Grid**:

```
using Microsoft.Graph
..........

// Get the events
        IUserEventsCollectionPage events = await graphClient.Me.Events.Request()
            .Select("subject,organizer,start,end")
            .OrderBy("createdDateTime DESC")
            .GetAsync();
```

**MainPage.Xaml with DataGrid**:

```
<Page
        ....>

    <Grid>
        <controls:DataGrid x:Name="EventList" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Organizer" Width="SizeToCells" Binding="{Binding Organizer.EmailAddress.Name}" FontSize="20" />
                <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Subject">
                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HyperlinkButton x:Name="hlBtnFileDownload" Content="{Binding subject}" Click="hlBtnFileDownload_Click"></HyperlinkButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                ..................
                ..................
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Button Click Event**:

I though code should be something similar to the following (as I have used it in `WPF` datagrid). But here I am not clear what should be the `ClassName` here since `IUserEventsCollectionPage` used in the above query is an Interface and an [online search](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=zIb7XtrRLf_BytMP1JOJ6As&q=IUserEventsCollectionPage&oq=IUserEventsCollectionPage&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1DsB1izFmDTGGgAcAB4AIABRogBiwGSAQEymAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwja54btl6rqAhX_oHIEHdRJAr0Q4dUDCAk&uact=5) does not give much info on this interface.

```
private void hlBtnFileDownload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ClassName classObj = dataGridName.SelectedItem as ClassName;
    string id = classObj.ID;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

To answer a question from user `@ Martin Zikmund`, the DataGrid ItemsSource is set as follows:

```
EventList.ItemsSource = events.CurrentPage.ToList();
```

Furthermore, I tried the following in the above button click event, but when clicking on cell it returns `eventitem`  below as null. Likewise, using `Event eventitem = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Event;` also return `eventitem` as null.

```
List<Event> eventitem = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as List<Event>;
            string st = eventitem[1].ToString();
```

Comment: How do you set the `DataGrid` ItemsSource?

Comment: @MartinZikmund I set it as`EventList.ItemsSource = events.CurrentPage.ToList();`

Comment: @MartinZikmund To answer your question I've also added an **UPDATE** section with more details.

Comment: Can your DataGrid display well? If you use `object eventitem = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;` , can it return the right DataContext or still null? If it is still null, can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT The DataGrid displays the data correctly. And when I click on the button inside a row it fires the click event successfully, as well. But the DataContext  is always null. For just a test, I tried `int index = EventList.SelectedIndex;` and noticed that it returns the correct index (row number), as well. It is just simple sample from MS Graph team [Get Calendar Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/uwp?tutorial-step=4). To simplify you can just return 2 columns `subject,organizer` and for `subject` column you can use `DataGridTemplateColumn` with button inside.

Comment: When I followed the tutorial you shared and clicked the HyperlinkButton, I could get the right DataContext by using `Event eventitem = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Event;`. So I can't reproduce your issue. It's better to provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT You are correct. I created a simple sample, with the online linked code, and tested the sample and it worked with `Event eventitem = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Event;`. I'll need to debug the code in my real app and see what I may be missing. I want to thank you for taking your time to look into the issue and trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items bound to individual cells are not `List<Event>` but just `Event` so the following should work:

```
var event = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Event;
```

Comment: @MartinZimu As I pointed out in the third line of my **UPDATE** section, I already had tried that. But it still returns `eventitem` as null. The click event triggers correctly and, I have tested, it does return correct index (EventList.SelectedIndex) as well. I've explained in my comment to `@Faywang-MSFT` how it can be tested. I'll also try to upload a sample somewhere and will let you and others know. There may be a time lapse in our responses  I'm in US EST time zone - and it's after 2:00AM here now.

Comment: @nam Oh, sorry, I completely missed that :-( ... I will try to test it locally too, but a simple repro on Github would be great :-)

Comment: You are correct, `Event eventitem = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as Event;` should have worked. I tested it by creating a simple sample from the online linked example (I gave above), and it worked. I would need to debug the code in my real app and check what I may be missing.

Comment: Glad it helped :-)